# Loading JSON data from a URL passing authentication parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have to consume a JSON from a URL, I'm using Springboot with jackson, when I post I send some authentication information in the header, the API expects SECRETKEY + ACCESSKEY + date I have all this information to send

```
 public void sendListPayload(int count, List object, String controller) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {

        Control type = Control.valueOf(controller);
        String endereco = getAdress(type);
        String payloadSecure = "";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://adress/site.php";
        HttpHeaders headers;
        String payload = convertListToJson(object);
        headers = getHeaders(count, payload);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(payloadSecure, headers);
         String answer = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);
         log.info(answer);
    }
```

GetHeader

```
public HttpHeaders getHeaders(int sizeRecords, String payloadSecure) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        String signature = "";
        signature = payloadSecure + SECRETKEY + ACCESSKEY + getISODate();
        String fullSignature = FIRSTPAYLOAD + getISODate() + ":" + Useful.toSha(signature);
        headers.add("HEADER", fullSignature);
          return headers;
```

The minified JSON I'm going to read will come like this

```
[{"relatorioID":"1852","professorID":"7","alunoID":"37","turmaID":"44","bimestre":"0","data":"2014-06-05 07:51:49","situacao":"1"},
{"relatorioID":"1854","professorID":"7","alunoID":"37","turmaID":"44","bimestre":"0","data":"2014-06-05 07:51:55","situacao":"1"}]
```

I already have an object with the same fields to instantiate with the JSON data
I'm very new to java and springboot, how do I get past secretkey and accesskey? Is it in the header of get mehod?

Then I have to transform JSON received into a list of objects using jackson ... to insert them into the local database.

Comment: what does your API expect from you in order to authenticate the request? if you can post a small desc from api docs on how to authenticate will help us figure it out

Comment: @slimane 
unfortunately I do not have access to the API now but I know she expects
 SECRETKEY + ACCESSKEY + date
I have all this information to send ..

Comment: it's a litle bit weird to send authentications in HEADER header. headers.add("HEADER", fullSignature); can you try Authorization  instead

Comment: but what would the get method look like?

Comment: in the code above, you are using post method.

Comment: in the code above, you are using post method.

Comment: is just an example of how I did the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the point is you need to be clear about the API specification that in which format your API expect the request. Anyways answering your question below code can help you to send your authentication parameters in the header and handle the response.

```
 import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
 import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents;
 import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
 import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
 //some more class import may be you need to add
  try {

    UriComponents uriComponents = 
     UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("https").host(host).path(url).
     queryParam("url_param1", value).queryParam("another_param", 
     value).build().encode();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("SECRETKEY", value);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
    ResponseEntity<List<MyResponseObject>> response = restTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyResponseObject>>());

    List<MyResponseObject > responses= response.getBody();

  } catch (Exception e) {
     logger.error(e.getMessage());
  }
```

Create `MyResponseObject` class to bind your response json property

```
public class MyResponseObject {

    @JsonProperty("relatorioID")
    private String relatorioID;



    @JsonProperty("professorID")
    private Integer professorID;

    ...


    //getter //setter
}
```

I hope this will help you to bind your params on the header and sent by encoding your query param in URL. Once you get the response in as a list of  `MyResponseObject` object.